# How to see time left in an interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

I'm looking at the timeout object for an interval, and I don't see any way actually figure out how long until that interval runs again.

I don't see anything in the node docs pointing to how this works, and most explanations just talk about "a timers thread that counts down", which I can't find out much more about.

Any clue how I could see or calculate how long until it runs again? Running on latest node in case that matters much

For context, the timer (setInterval) I'm working with is an hour long

```
Timeout {
 _idleTimeout: 3600000,
 _idlePrev: [Timeout],
 _idleNext: [Timeout],
 _idleStart: 5010,
 _onTimeout: [Function],
 _timerArgs: undefined,
 _repeat: 3600000,
 _destroyed: false,
 [Symbol(refed)]: true,
 [Symbol(asyncId)]: 1622,
 [Symbol(triggerId)]: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so based on node.js source

```
const Timer = process.binding('timer_wrap').Timer;


const timeLeft = timer => {
    timer.timeLeft = function () {
        if (this._called) return 0;
        return timer._idleStart + timer._idleTimeout - Timer.now()
    };
    return timer;
}


const timer = timeLeft(setTimeout(_ => console.log('hi'), 1000));

setInterval(_ => console.log('Time left: ', timer.timeLeft()), 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```js
const interval = setInterval(() => {console.log('hi')}, 10 * 1000)

setInterval(() => {
    const timeLeft = Math.round((interval._repeat - (performance.now() - interval._idleStart)) / 1000)
    console.dir(timeLeft)
}, 1000)
```